# Publishing ASP.NET Core 2.0 to IIS 8.5 Web.config struggles. Error 500.19

Tags: web-config, asp.net-core-2.0, iis-8.5

I have the following web.config file that is generated when I publish my app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    **<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\RLANInfrastructureCore.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />**
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I have put asterisks around what seems to be the offending line that causes problems when trying to run the site on IIS 8.5.

According to [this](https://forums.asp.net/t/2121840.aspx?ASP%20Net%20Core%20Publish%20HTTP%20Error%20500%2019%20Internal%20Server%20Error), I need to ensure that I have the ASP.NET Core Module installed in IIS, but I don't see it among my modules.  I have tried installing the dotnet-runtime-2.0.6 package as wlel as the ASPNetCore2.0.6Runtime Package but that didn't seem to too the module to the list on IIS.

I have tried referring to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/index?tabs=aspnetcore2x) in an effort to set things up but it is incredibly unclear.  My notion is I need to successfully add the ASP.NET Core module, perhaps from the files that I've installed but have no idea how to do so.  Would someone be able to offer direction on how to do so?

Is there anything else that might be the cause of my troubles?

Comment: Why cannot you scroll down to the second half of the article? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/index?tabs=aspnetcore2x#install-the-net-core-windows-server-hosting-bundle It clearly shows where to find the installer and install.

Comment: Although needlessly sassy (although expecting otherwise is on me), in reading through once again I'm realizing now that I installed the normal runtime package instead of the server package.  I now have the module.  Thank you.